# Error in specifying parameter of distribution in qqPlot

Tags: r

I am trying to compare a dataset with a given binomial distribution. Following the advice given in the R Documentation of `qqPlot` and `Distribution.df` I tried in this way:-\

```
dput(x)
structure(c(12, 16, 14, 13, 17, 14, 16, 15, 16, 20, 11, 15, 12, 
19, 15, 16, 16, 21, 17, 16, 18, 17, 13, 20, 16, 17, 11, 13, 11, 
20, 16, 20, 15, 14, 20, 20, 12, 13, 15, 9, 14, 18, 17, 15, 19, 
17, 14, 13, 13, 15, 13, 16, 19, 16, 13, 15, 16, 15, 11, 13, 14, 
13, 19, 12, 17, 12, 15, 14, 17, 16, 14, 15, 13, 14, 16, 14, 14, 
8, 14, 17, 13, 11, 15, 17, 13, 13, 13, 14, 18, 17, 14, 13, 19, 
14, 14, 11, 14, 14, 11, 19), .Dim = c(100L, 1L))
```

Now,

```
car::qqPlot(x,distribution="binom", param.list=list(size=30, prob=0.5))
```

The output shows an error like this

```
Error in q.function(P, ...) : 
  unused argument (param.list = list(size = 30, prob = 0.5))
```

I could not figure out what is going on.

Comment: Does this work for you: `car::qqPlot(x, distribution="binom", size = 30, prob = .5)`

Comment: But I face one problem....My x has 5000 observatios..but the Q-Q plot does seem like plotting 5000 points